# XFCE workspace margins inconsistent on multi-screen setup

Tags: workspace, margins, xfce

I use XFCE 4.12 with "workspace margins". Margins are needed in the case that you have a toolbar on an edge of your screen, and you want window autosizing to account for the toolbar.

Workspace margins treat the displays as one big screen. So if your monitors are different sizes (you have a laptop and are using a second monitor) the margins won't be respected on both screens.

What's the best workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to match the margin for *only the bottom edge*, you simply have to align the margins in your display management gui. But this does not answer the problem of margins for multiple edges.

Let's say you need to respect the bottom margin on two different sized screens:

### Before

[image: Before]

### After

[image: After]